# Modify moderncv header

Tags: moderncv

Is there a possibility to change the order of photo and name in the `moderncv` class using `\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual}`?

Right now it looks like this:

```
PHOTOPHOTO
PHOTOPHOTO
PHOTOPHOTO
PHOTOPHOTO
PHOTOPHOTO                      FirstName LastName
__________________________________________________
```

But actually I want it to look like this:

```
                                        PHOTOPHOTO
                                        PHOTOPHOTO
                                        PHOTOPHOTO
                                        PHOTOPHOTO
FirstName LastName                      PHOTOPHOTO
__________________________________________________
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 8):

You just need to change the `\maketitle` command:

```
% reverse the name and photo
\makeatletter
% maketitle
\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
  {%
    {\firstnamestyle{\@firstname}~\familynamestyle{\@familyname}}}%
    \hfill%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
      {}%
      {{\color{firstnamecolor}\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}\\[-.35em]}%
    {\color{firstnamecolor}\rule{\textwidth}{.25ex}\\[2.5em]}%
% optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering{}\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \maketitle
\makeatother
```

The hardest part is determining where to put this block of code.  The `\maketitle` command is defined not in `moderncv.cls`, but in the theme (package) file such as `moderncvthemecasual.sty`.  Moreover, the implementation of `\moderncvtheme` makes sure that this theme package is not loaded until the *end* of the preamble.

So if you want to do this once, put it in your cv TeX file, but it has to be expanded *after `\begin{document}` and before `\maketitle`*.  The best way to do this is to surround the block above with `\AtBeginDocument{...}` in the preamble, after `\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual}`.

If you want to do this more than once, you could copy the file `moderncvthemecasual.sty` and add a package option.  If this is beyond your expertise you may want to email the developers and see if they'll consider it.

Comment: Using `\AtBeginDocument{\makeatletter\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{...}\makeatother}` you can still put your code in the preamble.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: you are right, and that's a better answer.  I've edited.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if you really need to do all that trouble. Maybe you just want to use the `classic` theme that `moderncv` provides.
So you can try to use

```
\moderncv[blue]{classic}
```

instead of

```
\moderncv[blue]{casual}
```

The `classic` theme does place the photo on the right. I have summed up some information on the `moderncv` package at [*Moderncv LaTeX package. A really easy way to create a modern CV*](http://walrustech.wordpress.com/2011/11/18/moderncv-latex-package-a-really-easy-way-to-create-a-modern-cv/).