# Moderncv casual header - photo right, name and title on the left

Tags: header-footer, titles, moderncv

I like the `moderncv` `casual` theme, but I would like to change the order of the photo and the name / title.

I tried the solution described in this question:

[Modify moderncv header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13785/modify-moderncv-header)

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\maketitle ->{{\firstnamestyle 
                               {\@firstname}~\familynamestyle {\@familyname}...
l.33 \maketitle
```

Example code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual}
\AtBeginDocument
{
% reverse the name and photo
\makeatletter
% maketitle
\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
  {%
    {\firstnamestyle{\@firstname}~\familynamestyle{\@familyname}}}%
    \hfill%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
      {}%
      {{\color{firstnamecolor}\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}\\[-.35em]}%
    {\color{firstnamecolor}\rule{\textwidth}{.25ex}\\[2.5em]}%
% optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering{}\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \maketitle
\makeatother
}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}    
\address{Example Street}{12345 Exampe Town}
\photo{picture}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to solve the problem, that class `moderncv` has changed could be the following MWE. The part after `\AtBeginDocument` rewrites the original definition in `moderncv`.

**Please keep in mind**: if the class `moderncv` is changed again, you may need to change your corrections again. Perhaps it would be a good idea to ask the author of `moderncv` to integrate an option to change the position of name and picture.

The changed MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}
\mobile{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone{+2~(345)~678~901}
\fax{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}
\quote{Some quote}

\makeatletter
%\AtBeginDocument
%{
% reverse the name and photo
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  \recomputecvlengths%
  \makecvfooter%
  % define optional picture
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
      {
        \@initializelength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}% Damit Länge bekannt bei Name
        \settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{0pt}%
      }%
      {%
       \setlength\fboxrule{\@photoframewidth}%
       \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
         \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
       {\color{color1}\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}
        \@initializelength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}% Damit Länge bekannt bei Name
        \settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
      }%
  % end define optional picture

  % name
%    \parbox[b]{\textwidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{%
 {   \raggedright\namefont{\color{color2!50}\@firstname} {\color{color2}\@familyname}}%\lastname -> error
    \hfill\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
%    \parbox[b]{\textwidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{%
%   \raggedleft\namefont{\color{color2!50}\@firstname} {\color{color2}\@lastname}}%\familyname
\\[-.35em]%
  {\color{color2!50}\rule{\textwidth}{.25ex}}%
  % optional title
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\null\hfill\titlestyle{\@title}}\\[2.5em]% 
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\null\hfill\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\hfill\null\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% 
%}% AtBeginDocument ende
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{ \textit{Grade} }{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cvitem{title}{ \emph{Title} }
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvdoubleitem{category X}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category Y}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 3}
\end{document}
```

The result is:
[image: Result of MWE]

## Update to `moderncv` 2.0.0:

As already mentioned above class `moderncv` has changed and therefore you need the following code using class version `2.0.0`.

With the current version `moderncv 2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter document class` you can define for style `casual` with an additional option `[left]` to get the name printed left, the image right in the title of the CV as wished in this question.

Please see that there are new commands available to define phone numbers etc. and to add new infos like `linkedin` or `github` ...

Please see the following MWE (new code marked with `<======`):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle[left]{casual} % <========================================
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\name{John}{Doe} % <====================================================
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890} % <====================================
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901} % <=====================================
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012} % <=======================================
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe} % <=========================================
\social[twitter]{jdoe} % <==============================================
\social[github]{jdoe} % <===============================================
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}
\quote{Some quote}

\setlength{\footskip}{84pt} % <=========================================


\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{ \textit{Grade} }{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cvitem{title}{ \emph{Title} }
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvdoubleitem{category X}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category Y}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 3}
\end{document}
```

Please see that line `\setlength{\footskip}{84pt}` is only needed because I added more personal infos into the footer. For your CV please do not add this line, compile and check the `*.log` file for a warning, that `footskip is too small.` use the rounded value given in that warning for your CV ...

Comment: Great! As you said I suggested the author to implement such a feature.

Answer (score 8):

The updated version of moderncv makes this obsolete - there is an option included into the package to change this.
when you load the \moderncvstyle, include the option [left] like this:

```
\moderncvstyle[left]{casual}
```